# '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python

when trying to run the code below, I get the message "'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. since I am running it with a for I would have thought that the line "if data_copy[j] > data_copy[j+1]:" would be picking up individual elements from the list. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

```
data = [53,76,25,98,56,42,69,81]
```

```py
data_copy = data [:]
for i in range(len(data_copy)):
    for j in range(0,len(data_copy)-i-1):
        # print(data_copy[j])
        # print(data_copy[j+1])
        # print()
        if data_copy[j] > data_copy[j+1]:
            data_copy[j],data_copy[j+1] = data_copy[j+1],data_copy
print(data_copy)
```

Comment: Typo: you're missing `[j]` at the end of the swapping line

Comment: Look at the swapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `[j]` at the end of `data_copy[j],data_copy[j+1] = data_copy[j+1],data_copy`

should be: `data_copy[j],data_copy[j+1] = data_copy[j+1],data_copy[j]`

Answer (score 0):

In swapping, you didn't mention the index

```
data_copy = data [:]
for i in range(len(data_copy)):
    for j in range(0,len(data_copy)-i-1):
        # print(data_copy[j])
        # print(data_copy[j+1])
        # print()
        if data_copy[j] > data_copy[j+1]:
            data_copy[j],data_copy[j+1] = data_copy[j+1],data_copy[j]
print(data_copy)
```